# pandas Basic DataFrame concatenation not working in Python3

Tags: python, pandas

I'm doing a simple DataFrame concatenation tutorial for Python3. You can find this tutorial here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dealing-with-rows-and-columns-in-pandas-dataframe/

```
import pandas as pd

# importing numpy as np
import numpy as np
 
# making data frame 
df = pd.read_csv('nba.csv', index_col ='Name') 
  
df.head(10)
  
new_row = pd.DataFrame({'Name':'Geeks', 'Team':'Boston', 'Number':3,
                        'Position':'PG', 'Age':33, 'Height':'6-2',
                        'Weight':189, 'College':'MIT', 'Salary':99999},
                                                            index =[0])
# simply concatenate both dataframes
df_new = pd.concat([new_row, df]).reset_index(drop = True)
df_new.head(5)
print(df_new)
```

Upon attempting to print df_new I get this output

```
0    Geeks          Boston     3.0       PG  33.0    6-2   189.0                MIT    99999.0
1      NaN  Boston Celtics     0.0       PG  25.0    6-2   180.0              Texas  7730337.0
2      NaN  Boston Celtics    99.0       SF  25.0    6-6   235.0          Marquette  6796117.0
3      NaN  Boston Celtics    30.0       SG  27.0    6-5   205.0  Boston University        NaN
4      NaN  Boston Celtics    28.0       SG  22.0    6-5   185.0      Georgia State  1148640.0
..     ...             ...     ...      ...   ...    ...     ...                ...        ...
454    NaN       Utah Jazz     8.0       PG  26.0    6-3   203.0             Butler  2433333.0
455    NaN       Utah Jazz    25.0       PG  24.0    6-1   179.0                NaN   900000.0
456    NaN       Utah Jazz    21.0        C  26.0    7-3   256.0                NaN  2900000.0
457    NaN       Utah Jazz    24.0        C  26.0    7-0   231.0             Kansas   947276.0
458    NaN             NaN     NaN      NaN   NaN    NaN     NaN                NaN        NaN

[459 rows x 9 columns]
```

This is not the expected output. I was wondering if I was doing something wrong as I re-downloaded the csv in case the csv was corrupted somehow however that does not seem to be the case. I am new to python so I'm trying to figure out why DataFrame.head() is not working in terms of not reducing the output dataframe to 5 elements, and why the actual values are being set to null.

If anyone has any ideas let me know.

Comment: "DataFrame.head() is not working in terms of not reducing the output dataframe to 5 elements" because df.head() doesn't change the original dataframe, it just shows a view of the top n rows. Try either `print(df_new.head(5))` or `df_new=df_new.head(5)`

Comment: You put "Name" as index in your original dataframe. With that, you made it "dissapear" in `df` so when you try to concat a `Name` colum, it gets filled up with NaN. Just remove the `index_col ='Name'` from your original df

Comment: Your question should include a [mcve] without relying on an external link to understand, including a sample of the input dataframe and expected output with a description of how it's different from the current output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an error in the tutorial. Just read the CSV without "index_col='Name'", and run the same code and it will work

Answer (score 1):

Writting it as an answer too.

You put `"Name"` as index in your original dataframe. With that, you made it "dissapear" in df so when you try to concat a Name colum, it gets filled up with NaN. Just remove the `index_col ='Name'` from your original df.

`df = pd.read_csv('nba.csv')`